# declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: laravel

````
```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Class Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\ResultStatement::columnCount)
```
````

After five hours of downtime, refreshed the page and got it. Local server: OpenServer 5.2.2, Windows 7, Laravel 5.8, PhP 7.1.3, MySql 8.0 thx.

After reboot OpenServer, error disappeared

Comment: Can you check your composer.lock for the version of `symfony/dbal` in use?

Comment: I don't have symfony/dbal in file composer.lock

Have:
"name": "doctrine/dbal",
"version": "v2.9.2",